# Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers with $q = 2p + 1$. Prove that there is some multiple of $q$ such that the sum of its decimal digits is at most $3$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers with $q = 2p + 1$. Prove that there is some multiple of $q$ such that the sum of its decimal digits is at most $3$.

**MY IDEAS**

I started by listing out small $p, q$ and one multiple of $q$ such that the sum of its decimal digits is at most $3$. For example, when $p = 2, q = 5, 10$ satisfies the condition; when $p = 3, q = 7, \ 21$ satisfies the condition; when $p = 5, q = 11, \ 11$ satisfies the condition; when $p = 11, q = 23, \ 2001$ satisfies the condition; when $p = 23, q = 47, \ 10011$ satisfies the condition and so on.

I thought I could perhaps find a pattern, or use proof by contradiction, assuming that the sum of the decimal digits of all the multiples of $q$ are greater or equal to $4$. I don't think I'm using the condition with "decimal digits" properly. Can someone please help? Thank you so much!

Comment: Decimal digits implies modulo $10$, and in this case it implies $10^u+10^v+1$ with $u\ge v\ge 1$.

Comment: Oh I see! Let me try and use this in this question. Thanks so much!

Comment: If the order of $10$ $\pmod q$ is even (call it $2k$), then the claim is clear, as $10^{2k}+10^k\equiv 0\pmod q$.  At least that covers a lot of cases ($q=83$ being the least safe prime for which $10$ has odd order, barring computational error).

Comment: For what it's worth, $q=83$ gives $2×10^{19}+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already dealt with $p = 2$, consider only $p \gt 2$ so then $\gcd(q, 10) = 1$. Let the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $10$ modulo $q$ be

$$m = \operatorname{ord}_q(10)$$

A result of [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) is that

$$m \mid \varphi(q) \;\;\to\;\; m \mid 2p$$

With $m = 1$, we get $10 \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; q = 3$, which is not a valid value. As [Lulu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833067/let-p-and-q-be-prime-numbers-with-q-2p-1-prove-that-there-is-some-mul#comment10289440_4833067) suggests, with $m$ being even so $m = 2k$, we get

$$10^{k} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; 10^{k} \equiv -1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; 10^{k} + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$$

This handles the $m \in \{2, 2p\}$ cases so, since $p$ is an odd prime, the only other possible value of $m$ is $p$ itself. Consider

$$r_{i} = -10^{i} - 1, \;\; 1 \le i \le p$$

Assume there's no $i$ where $r_{i} \equiv 10^{j} \pmod{q}$ for some integer $j$. Thus, there are $p$ distinct non-zero congruence values modulo $q$ among the $10^{i}$ values, and $p$ additional corresponding distinct non-zero congruence values modulo $q$ among the $r_{i}$ values, for a total of $2p$ non-zero congruence values. Note the $r_i$ values are all non-zero because, otherwise, we get $r_{i} \equiv 0 \pmod{q} \;\to\; 10^{i} \equiv -1 \pmod{q}$. However, then $10^{2i} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; m \mid 2i \;\to\; p \mid 2i \;\to\; i = p$. But $10^{p} \equiv 1 \not\equiv -1 \pmod{q}$, a contradiction.

Also consider if for some $i$ that $r_{i} \equiv -1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; -10^{i} \equiv 0\pmod{q}$, but this isn't true. Thus, $-1$ is a non-zero congruence value which is not in either of the sets of $10^{i}$ or $r_{i}$ values, so adding this to the $2p$ values mentioned before gives $2p + 1$ such distinct non-zero congruence values. However, there are only $q - 1 = 2p$ such values in total. This contradiction means the assumption about the uniqueness of congruences can't be true, i.e., there must be a $1 \le i \le p$ such that a $1 \le j \le p$ exists where

$$10^{j} \equiv r_{i} \pmod{q} \;\to\; 10^{j} \equiv -10^{i} - 1 \pmod{q} \;\to\; 10^{j} + 10^{i} + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$$